# Is there any way of drawing a variable rectangle using the Graphics class

Tags: java, awt, rectangles

I have coded a simple Java game where there are two rectangles on the screen, one of the rectangles moves and the other stays still, the moving Rectangle moves with keyboard arrow input and can move either up, down, left or right. The problem I am having is drawing my rectangles on the screen, I mean I have the 2 rectangles set up with my variables as shown:

```
Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(shiftX, shiftY,90,90);
Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(500 + buckyPositionX, 330 + buckyPositionY, 210, 150);
```

I have made a render method to draw the things on the screen which I want shown:

```
 public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException{
}
```

The problem I am having is showing my rectangles on the screen by writing the code in the render method, I could do the following:

```
g.fillRect(x, y,90,90);
g.fillRect(500 + buckyPositionX, 330 + buckyPositionY, 210, 150);
```

Which makes 2 rectangles on the screen but I need the rectangles to be drawn using the Rectangle code written with the variables, I have been told this can be done using Graphics2D but I am wondering if there is a simpler way of just using the graphics function, if not could you please help me set this up?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can access attributes of the `Rectangle` instances easily:

```
g.fillRect(rectOne.getX(), rectOne.getY(), rectOne.getWidth(), rectOne.getHeight());
```

In any case mind that usually the `Graphics` object is a `Graphics2D` instance at runtime so this could work easily too:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
g2d.fill(rectOne);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I now have a new problem which you may be able to help me with, I used the fillRect(rectOne.getX()... and got a error saying that the method fillRect takes (float,float,float.float) and not (double,double,double,double), I think this may be because of my variables, my rectOne requires shiftX and shiftY variables and rectTwo required buckyPositionX and buckyPositionY, all these variables are int and if I change them to float my Rectangle variables get errors but if I change them to int the fillRect gets errors, how do I fix this please?

Comment: Cast them to double or use Rectangle2D.Double instead that Rectangle, which is an inner class just for this.

Comment: I have tried but keep getting the following error under the fillRect: "This method fillRect(float,float,float,float) in the type graphics is not applicable for the arguments (double,double,double,double)"

Comment: Then try with Rectangle2D.Float class and PLEASE start reading documentation and API reference.

Comment: I also tried the float method before and got the same error, also is this the API reference http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/?

Comment: Yes, specifically: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html and

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
g.fillRect(myRect.getX(), myRect.getY(), myRect.getWidth(), myRect.getHeight());
```

where `myRect` is the rectangle you want to draw. You could even make a custom method `drawRect(Graphics g, Rectangle myRect);` if you have lots of rectangles to draw.

Using [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) is not that difficult as well, as the provide `Graphics` object normally is a `Graphics2D` object:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
g2d.fill(myRect);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I now have a new problem which you may be able to help me with, I used the fillRect(rectOne.getX()... and got a error saying that the method fillRect takes (float,float,float.float) and not (double,double,double,double), I think this may be because of my variables, my rectOne requires shiftX and shiftY variables and rectTwo required buckyPositionX and buckyPositionY, all these variables are int and if I change them to float my Rectangle variables get errors but if I change them to int the fillRect gets errors, how do I fix this please?

Comment: Just cast the `double` values to `float` when you pass them to `fillRect()` you won't see the difference due to a lower precision on your screen.

Comment: I tried your method and changed everything to float but no matter what I try I continue getting the following error under fillRect: "This method fillRect(float,float,float,float) in the type graphics is not applicable for the arguments (double,double,double,double)"

Comment: Open a new question where you state your new problem including the updated code, it seems that we are not able to solve your new problem in the comments...